# my Promise catches an exception and I don't know how to print the error message

Tags: javascript, error-handling

This seems really simple, I just can't figure out.
I have a Javascript Promise, which throws an exception and is  caught in the .catch() section.  I know how to fix the exception, but I can't figure out how to display to my user the exception's error message

```
    Promise.all([
        getSomethingThatBreaks(),
    ]).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);           // Proxy object
        console.log(error.body);      // Same Proxy object
        console.log(error.status);    // "400"
        console.log(error.statusText);// "Bad Request"
        console.log(error.message);   // "undefined"
        console.log(error.target);    // "undefined"
   })
```

If I inspect the console, I see the error message in the resulting Proxy Object.  It looks to me like "console.log(error.message) should return "Attempt to de-reference a null object" but it is undefined.
What stupidly simple thing am I overlooking?

[image]

Comment: At a cursory glance, it looks like `error.body.message`

Comment: @Phil  :-) Hey, that worked!  Thank You.  I knew it would be simple. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.  It's embarrassingly easy, so I'm almost tempted to delete the whole question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compliments of @Phil this works:
console.log(error.body.message);